# Splitting a string with two (x,y) integers in it - Java

Tags: java, string, split, integer

My question is simply - I have a string that is "2 1". 
2 is to represent the int x coordinate and 1 is to represent the y coordinate.

I wan't my result to be something like this:

```
int x;

int y;

Sting example = "2 1";
```

//some sort of split happens

result..

```
x = 2 //these are both integers

y = 1
```

I was thinking of doing a substring for the 2 and the 1...then converting it to an int. -- maybe there is another way? a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine a [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
String example = "2 1";
String[] arr = example.split("\\s+"); // <-- one (or more) whitespace
int x = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use some kind of delimiter(say ~) to seperate your x coordinate and y coordinate. Then you can simply do like this.

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(example.split("~")[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(example.split("~")[1]);
```